# Setting Content Size of UIScrollView inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented page view in my app. It has three pages. On second page, there is scroll view and i have set its content size in viewWillAppear method. It works fine when i visit second page for the first time, but when i go to 3rd page and return on second page, content size isn't always set. Sometimes its set but that too takes few seconds and then scrolling starts. Can anyone please help?

Also, can anyone please tell me which method is ALWAYS called whenever we navigate in UIPageViewController from one page to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the contentSize in

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
     // your code here
}
```

method, because this method is called after `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. There is just one thing, setting contentSize doesn't work if put directly in viewWillLayoutSubviews method. I had to apply performSelector with 0.5 seconds and then set contentSize in another method and now its working with 0.5 sec delay. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Maverick can you pleaase tell what you did to resolve it I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Abhishek It's an old post from one of my old projects. My comment above your comment already mentions what I did to resolve it. Apart from that, I really don't remember anything significant. Just try setting ScrollView's content size in `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` overridden method, and if it doesn't help then try setting content size with 0.5 sec delay using performSelector. Hope it'll work for you, as it worked for me.